# Way to call super(MyClass, self).__init__() without MyClass?

Tags: python, syntax

I find this syntax astoundingly annoying. Every time I rename my class, I have to change this call for no apparent reason. Isn't there some `__class__` magic variable or something I can use at least? Interested in answers for Python 2.5, but it doesn't hurt to know if later versions fixed this.

Comment: You're not alone: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class only inherits from **one** class it is safe to do just this:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)
```

<del>But I could be mistaken.</del>

Comment: Oh.. well that's not nearly as bad! Why wouldn't this work when it inherits from more than one class? You're explicitly telling it which one you want to use...

Comment: @Mark: Yeah well of course you can explicitly list every class that your class inherits from. But I don't know how `super()` works internally so maybe it does some sophisticated stuff to initialize everything in the right order. I was more thinking of the fact that you should use `super()` to call any parents method as it makes sure that the right method is called if the class inherits from more than one class. That's why I wrote *safe* as I am definitely sure about this with one class but not about how it behaves with more classes.

Comment: If your class only inherits from one class and you do this, *your* class will work fine. This doesn't mean that classes later on that *inherit your class* will work fine. `super` is the more general solution.

Comment: @Mark, imagine you also make `class C(A)` then `class D(B, C)`. How do you write `D.__init__` such that everyone's `__init__` is called exactly once?

Comment: @Mike: Hrm..? First B would be initialized, then C, then A, then ... oh, I see the problem now :D I don't think I've ever really had a need for multiple inheritance anyway.

Comment: @Mark, you don't need actually to use MI to avoid making your classes needlessly rigid.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, this isn't possible in 2.5.  However, in 3.0, this was changed so that you can simply call `super().__init__()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in Python 3.  http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.0, the [super()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#super) can be called without arguments to do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Alex, this causes infinite recursion when there is more than a single level of inheritance. Do not use this approach.

Yes, "new" style classes have a `__class__` attribute available which can be used, eg.

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B.__init__():"

class D(B):
    def __init__(self):
        print "D.__init__():"
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()

>>> d = D()
D.__init__():
B.__init__():

>>> dir(d)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__str__', '__weakref__']
>>> d.__class__
<class '__main__.D'>
```

However this fails if a class were to inherit from `D`:

```
>>> class E(D):
...     pass
...
>>> E()
D.__init__():
D.__init__():
[...]
D.__init__():
D.__init__():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  [...]
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: **wrong**!  Add a `class E(D): pass` and try doing `e = E()`: you get a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` exception because `D.__init__` is calling itself (`self.__class__` is `E` so its `super` is `D` --> infinine recursion).

Comment: @Alex Martelli: Sounds reasonable.